# Remove margin space of scrollbars in webview

Tags: android, webview

I use a webview (see white + red area) with no padding (see text reaches complete webview area). But the scollbars (see gray bars) are set a little inside the webview. How can I remove the space (see red markings) between scrollbars and webview outline? I want the scollbars inside webview but with no gap to outline.

[image]